# The import de.hybris.platform.core.model.user.UserModel cannot be resolved in hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

all. At first, everything was working fine but after `ant build` The import de.hybris.platform.core.model.user.UserModel cannot be resolved error appeared. I checked the location and there is no UserModel anymore.  I did `ant clean all` it build successfully, in eclipse did `project -> clean` several times but error steel exists. Any idea how to solve this.

Comment: did you check your localextensions.xml file?

Comment: Are you getting this error while server start up ? or it is just there in eclipse workspace ?

Comment: It is in eclipse workspace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Udaib Khan said cleaning eclipse work-space and `run ant all` at platform works. But whenever I change smth in code the problem occurs again. I solved it by unchecked **Eclipse (Project-->Build Automatically)**.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you imported the **platform** project in your IDE, then refresh.

Comment: Yes, I have imported it. It works fine after importing **platform**. But after modifying core item.xml file and building project, same error. Now I am thinking the problem with eclipse. I try to update it, see what happens.

Comment: You shouldn't modify core-items.xml. Instead, extend the type in your own extension **myextension-items.xml**.
You don't have to create a new type, you can add new attribute to existing type. Just redeclare the type then define generate & autocreate attributes to false.

Answer (score 0):

just clean your eclipse work-space and then run ant clean all at platform directory